# Reading 'medium created' date from mp4 files in C#

Tags: c#, .net, metadata, mp4

I'm making a program which renames images and videos (mainly mp4) to the date when they where originally created. I managed to read the metadata from images with Bitmaps without any problems, but I can't find anything to read the date from videos.

I tried some libarys to read the metadata from videos but they don't show the 'medium created' metadata.
I also tried "File.GetCreationTime()" but there you get the date when the file was created on this PC and not when it was originally created.

For images I used this code:

```
BitmapSource img = BitmapFrame.Create(fs);
BitmapMetadata md = (BitmapMetadata)img.Metadata;
string dateOriginal = md.DateTaken;
```

It would be ideal if would work like this with videos.
But it would be fine, if it is only possible with more code.

The output of the code should be 'dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm:ss'. For example: '27.08.2017 15:32:23'